# How to get a superscript in Qt Creator for label text?

Tags: qt-creator, text-formatting, superscript, richtext

I am trying to create a superscript of a 2 to show something is squared for the units label that comes after a field the user supplies in my dialog.  I am using Qt Creator v2.0.1 on Windows.  The QLabel has a text field and a textFormat field.  I attempted to solve this by setting the textFormat combobox to RichText and then set the textFormat field to be: "µm{\super 2}" however, when previewing my dialog, the text is taken literally and not as RichText and thus there is no superscript 2 but instead the '{super 2}' with the backslash removed.  I also tried escaping the backslash with '{\super 2}' but I then the literal '{\super 2}' when previewing the dialog.

How can I specify the superscript to Qt Creator so that my dialog preview shows the superscripted 2?

Here is how I want it to look: µm<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently html works (not sure why RichText did not):

```
µm<sup>2</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another easier way which is similar to @WilliamKF solution but it is easier for me.

for example, we have one QLabel in our UI like this :

1. For adding I right-click on that label and choose `Change rich text ...` and I will see this Dialog.

[image]

2. There I can easily write what I want and add **superscript** like this:

[image]

Then if I click Ok I have what I want and also I can choose `source` to see HTML tags :

```
<html><head/><body><p><span style=" font-size:16pt;">µm</span><span style=" font-size:16pt; vertical-align:super;">2</span></p></body></html>
```

[image]