# How to get a superscript in QTableWidget header?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I found out from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672994/how-to-get-a-superscript-in-qt-creator-for-label-text) question that If I want to have superscript in labels I can use this solution:

```
µm<sup>2</sup>
```

which means that I can use `HTML` tags and it works well.

but when I tried this way in `QTableWidget`, it didn't work.
**This is its result:**

[image]

I try other HTML tags which work in QLabel but none of them work for `QTableWidgetItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for having superscript in the QTableWidget header :

We should use only [Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) **for example**:

```
    QTableWidgetItem *___qtablewidgetitem = tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(0);
    ___qtablewidgetitem->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("MainWindow", "x\302\262", nullptr));
    QTableWidgetItem *___qtablewidgetitem1 = tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(1);
    ___qtablewidgetitem1->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("MainWindow", "x\302\263", nullptr));
    QTableWidgetItem *___qtablewidgetitem2 = tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(2);
    ___qtablewidgetitem2->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("MainWindow", "x\342\202\211", nullptr));
```

In the above example, I use `"x\302\262"` to see **x²**.

**This will be the result**

[image]

**Because it may be difficult to know these numbers, I used an [online keyboard](https://gate2home.com/English-Keyboard).**

[image]

**I wrote the content I wanted to see in the header here and after that I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Table's header UI.
then Qt will generate Unicode forms in `"ui_mainwindow.h"` file.**

As I mentioned characters should be Unicode so for example I test typing my text in LibreOffice and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> **`x²`** from there but it didn't understand and show **`x2`** in the header.